# How to make a functional component store props in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So currently I am able to pass in props and access what is returned within the same component, but I wanted to redirect to a new page and still be able to access the data within the component the data was passed into. These are my two components, props.value is undefined when accessed inside the Child component after redirecting to it.

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import React from 'react'
import Child from './Child'

function Parent() {
    function handleClick(){
        <Child value="something"/>
        console.log("I WAS CLICKED")
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</button>
            <Child value="Something" /> //Accessing component within the same component works
        </div>
    )
}

export default Parent
```

```
function Child (props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{props.value + " test"}</h1>
            <h1>TEST Data</h1>
        </div>
        
    )
}

export default Child
```

Comment: So in other words you want to preserve the data in the component? Then you should use something like redux

Comment: Have a look at redux or react context

Comment: Okay, thank you for the suggestions I will take a look. I wonder if there is a way to conditional render based on whether the button was clicked or not so that the child component can be displayed on the same page. What do you think about that?